# azure WEBSITE_NAME appsetting is missing

Tags: azure, configuration, .net-4.5, configurationmanager

Reading through the azure documentation and various posts on here, i understand there should be a number of settings available to web apps running on azure, among them `WEBSITE_HOSTNAME`and `WEBSITE_SITE_NAME`. These should also overwrite any existing configuration appsettings with same key.

When i attempt to run my app, it is reading the key from the config file (i.e. its not being overwritten by azure). If i remove the value from the config, i get an exception about not being able to pick up a config value.

Is there a step im missing? Are these values only available at certain tiers?

Answer (score 0):

Those values are only available as environment variables, so you'll need to read them from there.

App settings set in the Web App blade override settings and become env variables, but these are just environment variables.